# IE 11 cannot set breakpoint in javascript file added to HTML page

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have an HTML page that has an embedded javascript file that for some reason or another I cannot debug. I can click on the error line to go to the location in the code but once there I cannot actually set a breakpoint inside the IE 11 debugger. I can however set a breakpoint in the HTML which isn't helpful to me.

I've read similar posts on the topic but they haven't helped. I've unchecked the box that disables script debugging in the IE 11 options.

Does anyone know what could actively prevent the debugging from happening? Even console.log lines aren't making it through...

Thanks.

edit: the exact error I'm getting is SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier on an Object.entries().forEach call that I've already added the necessary polyfills for.

Comment: put in a global handler to suppress the errors window.onerror=function(){return true;}

Comment: try with `( Object.entries() ).forEach...` and see what happens. There's a god chance that your `Object` has no property called `entries` or your `entries` method is poorly written and is returning null, false,"",0 or some other faulty value instead of an empty array `[]` when no entries are encountered.